# How to customize VsCode Toolbar

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code, customization, toolbar

Under `Visual Studio Code` I would like to change the color of the `Git` `Changes` and `Stagged` title (put some color on them). Is there a setting I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with the workaround proposed in @Alain BUFFERNE's answer  you will have to change this file after **every** vscode update.

Alternatively you can use extension [Custom CSS and JS](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css). Just put the same code in your custom.css file.

Comment: Sure, I was not really proud of the workaround because of the updates. I didn't know about custom css and Js. I will dig into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately at this moment all configurable color theme options are listed here: [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference) and there is a limited option for customizing. Even the:

```
`{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sideBarSectionHeader.background": "#FFF"
  }
}`
```

which works for Explorer or debug sidebar does not work in the git sidebar...

Comment: Ok thanks, I will wait and for the moment do it by modifying workbench.main.css with .monaco-list-row>.resource-group>.name  selector

Answer (score 0):

Just my workaround to wait for theming for these.
In

> C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser/workbench.main.css:

```
 .monaco-list-row>.resource-group>.name {
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 18;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        color: red;
    }
```